# Formatting text data with C++ or any windows scripting language

Tags: c++, windows, file, text, formatting

This may be a simple task but at the moment I really have no clue how I could do this in a simple way.
I have the following situation, I have a script written in COFFEE, the scripting language of the 3D program Cinema 4D.
Now this script is writing position data in the following format into a text file (rtf in that case but can be a .txt aswell).

```
0  0.0  471.2  0.0
1  0.0  470.5  0.0
2  0.0  468.8  0.0
3  0.0  465.9  0.0
4  0.0  461.9  0.0
5  0.0  456.8  0.0
6  0.0  450.5  0.0
7  0.0  443.2  0.0
8  0.0  434.8  0.0
9  0.0  425.2  0.0
```

Frame, X, Y, Z.

Now what I need to do is getting this position data into this format:

```
Transform   Position
    Frame   X pixels    Y pixels    Z pixels    
    0   0.0    471.2    0.0 
    1   0.0    470.5    0.0 
    2   0.0    468.8    0.0 


End of Keyframe Data
```

It is not really visible here but there are no spaces in here, everything is spaced with tab (maybe copy that to notepad to really see the tabs). It's important that I have tabs between every number, there can be spaces but I need exactly one tab character everytime.
So the most important part is, how do I get those numbers from the first data set and bring and let the program add a \t between every number?

I tried to do this within the script but the script fails if I use a tab instead of several spaces between my positions.
I searched quite a lot but couldn't find any good solution for this.
I'm familiar with C++ and a little batch script but I'm happy for every solution even if I have to learn the basics of another language.

I tried to find a way in C++ but no way that I came up with could format an n number of lines and every single one was way to complicated. The number of frames/lines varies everytime so I never have a fixed line count.

Comment: How does the first set of data transform into the second set of data?  Right now it looks like you're using something just made up as an example since the two sets don't seem to represent the same thing.

Comment: No they are actual data generated from the script.
The second set is made manually but in the format how I need it to process it in another program.
Don't get confused by the 4.00002 frame number, that has something to do with the frame rate I choose. All I need is the 4 numbers from each line to have a tab before the actual number.
Meaning: Tab 1 Tab 2 Tab 3 Tab 4
Same thing with the Text that comes before the position data in the second data set. No spaces, just tabs for everything.

Comment: I edited the second set, should be more clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work.  I didn't do any special formatting of the numbers, so if you need that you'll need to add it.  If you're worried about a malformed input file, like not enough numbers on a line then you'd want to add some additional error checking to guard against it.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool Convert(const char* InputFilename, const char* OutputFilename)
{
    std::ifstream InFile(InputFilename);
    if(!InFile)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open  input file '" << InputFilename << "'" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    struct PositionData
    {
        double FrameNum;
        double X;
        double Y;
        double Z;
    };
    typedef std::vector<PositionData> PositionVec;

    PositionVec Positions;
    PositionData Pos;
    while(InFile)
    {
        InFile >> Pos.FrameNum >> Pos.X >> Pos.Y >> Pos.Z;
        Positions.push_back(Pos);
    }

    std::ofstream OutFile(OutputFilename);
    if(!OutFile)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open output file '" << OutputFilename << "'" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    OutFile << "Transform\tPosition\n\tFrame\tX pixels\tY pixels\tZ pixels" << std::endl;
    for(PositionVec::iterator it = Positions.begin(); it != Positions.end(); ++it)
    {
        const PositionData& p(*it);
        OutFile << "\t" << p.FrameNum << "\t" << p.X << "\t" << p.Y << "\t" << p.Z << std::endl;
    }
    OutFile << "End of Keyframe Data" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: convert <input filename> <output filename>" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    bool Success = Convert(argv[1], argv[2]);

    return Success;
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks so far!
I just have one question, may be a little silly but where do I actually set input file and output file?
I haven't used vector.h so far

Comment: Meh pressed entet to early.
Do I have just have to add `ofstream InFile ("example.txt");` ?

Comment: You supply them on the command line, so `convert input.txt output.txt` assuming you name the program convert.

Comment: Wait, this really confuses me :D
Haven't seen this kind of usage before. I specify the file names in the string without removing the ""?
Because either way, it doesn't really seem to work :/
With it being a string I get just the cout printed, the files are untouched. When I only have `convert <input.txt> <output.txt>` I get a compile error. Well of course, `convert` isn't specified anywhere.

Comment: I accepted the answer, from what I understand from the code it should definitely do what I want. Just how I specify in and output isn't clear to me so far. Which has more to do with my amateur C++ skills I guess :)

Comment: Ok, my usage message may be confusing.  I use `<something>` to indicate you should put something specific there, not that you should enclose it in `<>`.  So, `convert input.txt output.txt` would be what you typed at a command prompt.  You would only need quotes if your filenames had spaces, like `convert "filename with spaces.txt" "output file with spaces.txt"`

Comment: So if I understand correctly I should have `std::cout << convert input.txt output.txt << std::endl;` ?
In that case I get an error because `convert` isn't declared. If use `std::cout << "convert input.txt output.txt" << std::endl;` nothing happens.
Where do you actually retrive those file names for the actual processing because all I see happening in that line is that this string gets printed to the screen with cout :s

Comment: The original was meant to be a standalone program that you would compile and call from the command line in a script or something like that since that seemed to be what you wanted to do.  I replaced the code with a new version with a standalone Convert function.  You call it with the desired input filename and output filename.  Good luck.

Comment: Oh sorry, bad communication I guess. That works perfectly now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

yet another example using regexps

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream inf("TextFile1.txt");
    string data((istreambuf_iterator<char>(inf)), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    regex reg("([\\d|\.]+)\\s+([\\d|\.]+)\\s+([\\d|\.]+)\\s+([\\d|\.]+)");  
    sregex_iterator beg(data.cbegin(), data.cend(), reg), end;

    cout << "Transform\tPosition" << endl;
    cout << "\tFrame\tX pixels\tY pixels\tZ pixels" << endl;
    for_each(beg, end, [](const smatch& m) {
        std::cout << "\t" << m.str(1) << "\t" << m.str(2) << "\t" << m.str(3) << "\t" << m.str(4) << std::endl;
    });
    cout << "End of Keyframe Data" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example Python script if interested.

```
#!c:/Python/python.exe -u
# Or point it at your desired Python path
# Or on Unix something like: !/usr/bin/python

# Function to reformat the data as requested.
def reformat_data(input_file, output_file):

    # Define the comment lines you'll write.
    header_str = "Transform\tPosition\n"
    column_str = "\tFrame\tX pixels\tY pixels\tZ pixels\n"
    closer_str = "End of Keyframe Data\n"

    # Open the file for reading and close after getting lines.
    try:
        infile = open(input_file)
    except IOError:
        print "Invalid input file name..."
        exit()

    lines = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    # Open the output for writing. Write data then close.
    try:
        outfile = open(output_file,'w')
    except IOError:
        print "Invalid output file name..."
        exit()

    outfile.write(header_str)
    outfile.write(column_str)

    # Reformat each line to be tab-separated.
    for line in lines:
        line_data = line.split()
        if not (len(line_data) == 4):
            # This skips bad data lines, modify behavior if skipping not desired.
            pass 
        else:
            outfile.write("\t".join(line_data)+"\n")

    outfile.write(closer_str)
    outfile.close()

#####
# This below gets executed if you call
# python <name_of_this_script>.py
# from the Powershell/Cygwin/other terminal.
#####
if __name__ == "__main__":
    reformat_data("/path/to/input.txt", "/path/to/output.txt")
```